# Close holes near extent border

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I have a shapefile that looks like this:
[image]

The yellow polygon is a square of full extent size (not separate polygons) with class 0. Polygons of other colors have other classes (1, 2).
Looking closer to the left side, one can see small holes:

[image]

The same is in the upper left corner:
[image]

Additionally, there are situations where 2 Polygons are touching each other and both touch the hole:

[image]

I need to join each hole that touches the border to the Polygon of classes 1 and 2 that touches that hole and border. At the same time, I should not touch the "main part" of the class 0 (yellow) Polygon (I tried to highlight it by red color):
[image]

The problem is that I cannot come up with the feature for my python-code saying which "hole" of class 0 should belong to which Polygon of class 1 or 2. Seems like it should sound like "if the hole is surrounded by Polygon of class 1 or 2, join them", but I guess there is a more determinant explanation.

Comment: What class will you assign to the polygons that share borders with class 1 and class 2?

Comment: it doesn't matter.